# WP rest api v2 in production

Tags: angularjs, wordpress, api, wp-api

currently I'm working in a WordPress project. I would like to do a AngularJs frontend that consumes the data from WordPress CMS but I'm not sure it's a good idea. I have some questions about this:

Is wp-api v2 ready for production environment?
If not is ready, is good idea to use v1?
In the case of I will use the API, does it work fine with woocommerce?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I personally will advise you to use v2 instead of v1. I can't guarantee you if its  production ready or not, but there are more improvements on v2.

I use it in my Android apps and it works perfect.

There are lots of new changes including using the _embedded field which now contains the [featured image data](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails) called *featured_media* which was formerly *featured_image* for your post .

If you need a Woocommerce api, that is totally different from Wordpress Rest api, See Link here: http://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/